# How to set url in index.html in swagger-UI

Tags: javascript, java, jax-rs, swagger-ui

I am using Swagger-UI for jax-rs jersey.

So there is this index.html. There you have to enter the url for the swagger.json .

So this is a big problem.

We are deploying our application to a lot different environments.
And the respective swagger.json will always be on the same environment.
We have Jenkins build jobs and we cannot edit index.html for every environment.

```
    window.onload = function() {
  // Begin Swagger UI call region
  const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
    url: "**https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json**",
```

Property url I always have to set.

What should I do?

P.S.

In Springfox Swagger-UI there is no physical swagger.json
But in jax-rs I have this dist folder and there is always a physical json
as far as I understand. Where should I put this so all different
clients can access it.

Comment: Please share bit more of information. I think you should look in to set multi environment files. Like for production stage and dev. 
I jinkins you can build as per need with respective environment configurations.
Plz share what you have done so far so we can look into it in detail. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use vanilla JS for that:

```js
 var currentUrl = window.location.origin;
 var apiBasePath = currentUrl + '/v2';

 window.ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
        url: apiBasePath + "/swagger.json",
...
})
```

Comment: OK. Thanks. Sounds interesting. But why is it not possible to just say . url: "C:\users\myUser\swagger.json" . I mean that would be same as your solution , having an absolute path afterwards.